# "Syscall param open(mode) contains uninitialised byte(s)" in open sys call

Tags: c, linux, io, system-calls

```
fd = open(pathname, O_WRONLY | O_LARGEFILE | O_APPEND | O_CREAT);
```

When running my tests I encounter a valgrind error:

```
==14280== Syscall param open(mode) contains uninitialised byte(s)
==14280==    at 0x4111084: open64 (open64.c:42)
```

And the return value of `open` is `-2`

Errno is set to `13 (Permission denied)`

The `pathname` buffer contains:

```
0x68
0x72
0x32
0x2E
0x66
0x61
0x0
```

Info about my system:

```
$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 7 rzetterberg zed 4096 Jul  4 13:56 .
$ id
uid=1000(rzetterberg) gid=1000(rzetterberg) groups=1000(rzetterberg), ... etc
$ sudo file -Ls /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: sticky Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=XXXX (needs journal recovery) (large files)
$ uname -a
Linux xxxx 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Headers included:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

I don't understand how `mode` can have unitialised bytes and why I'm getting a `Permission denied`. It seems very strange to me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you supply the `O_CREAT` flag to `open()`, you must supply a third argument.  This is an integer which represents the permissions to apply to the created file (modified by the current `umask`).

Comment: Thank you, caf! I read this from the open(2): "If the file does not exist it will be created. The owner (user ID) of the file is set to the effective user ID of the process. The group ownership (group ID) is set either to the effective group ID of the process or to the group ID of the parent directory (depending on file system type and mount options, and the mode of the parent directory, see the mount options bsdgroups and sysvgroups described in mount(8))."

Comment: Now that I re-read the man pages I noticed this: "This argument must be supplied when O_CREAT is specified in flags;" -facepalm-

Answer (score 2):

When you call `open` with `O_CREAT` you need a third argument to the system call. That parameter is called `mode`. Valgrind is reporting uninitialized bytes because it doesn't know that you didn't specify the argument, but it sees that whatever happened to be on the stack isn't what it expects.